# IBM Watson SpechtoTextV1 error - Python

Tags: python, watson

I have been trying my hands on IBM Watson speechtotext api. However, it works with short length audio files, but not with audio files which are around 5 mins. It's giving me below error 
"watson {'code_description': 'Bad Request', 'code': 400, 'error': 'No speech detected for 30s.'}"

I am using Watson's trial account. Is there a limitation in case of trial account? or bug in below code.

Python code:-

```
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    username='XXX', 
    password='XXX',
    x_watson_learning_opt_out=False
)

with open('trial.flac', 'rb') as audio_file:
    print(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/flac', model='en-US_NarrowbandModel', timestamps=False, word_confidence=False, continuous=True))
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is there understandable speech during the first 30 seconds of your audio file? A suggestion: cut the first 30 seconds and create a new, smaller file. Try with that. It might give a better idea and help debugging.

Comment: Code seems to work with similar files(1 or 2 or 5 or 12 mins). If continuous=True is removed from the code, then it returns first 10 seconds conversion of above mentioned file.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the implementation notes from the Speech to Text API Explorer for the recognize API you are attempting to use:

> **Implementation Notes**
>
> Sends audio and returns transcription results for
> a sessionless recognition request. Returns only the final results; to
> enable interim results, use session-based requests or the WebSocket
> API. The service imposes a data size limit of 100 MB. It automatically
> detects the endianness of the incoming audio and, for audio that
> includes multiple channels, downmixes the audio to one-channel mono
> during transcoding.
>
> **Streaming mode**
>
> For requests to transcribe live
> audio as it becomes available or to transcribe multiple audio files
> with multipart requests, you must set the Transfer-Encoding header to
> chunked to use streaming mode. In streaming mode, the server closes
> the connection (status code 408) if the service receives no data chunk
> for 30 seconds and the service has no audio to transcribe for 30
> seconds. The server also closes the connection (status code 400) if no
> speech is detected for inactivity_timeout seconds of audio (not
> processing time); use the inactivity_timeout parameter to change the
> default of 30 seconds.

There are two factors here. First there is a data size limit of 100 MB, so I would make sure you do not send files larger then that to the Speech to Text service. Secondly, you can see the server will close the connection and return a 400 error if there is no speech detected for the amount of seconds defined for inactivity_timeout. It seems the default value is 30 seconds, so this matches the error you are seeing above.

I would suggest you make sure there is valid speech in the first 30 seconds of your file and/or make the inactivity_timeout parameter larger to see if the problem still exists. To make things easier, you can test the failing file and other sound files by using the API Explorer in a browser:

[Speech to Text API Explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/speech-to-text-v1#!/sessionless/recognizeSessionless)

Answer (score 2):

In the API documentation, there is this python code, it will avoid to close the server when the default 30s finishes, and works for other errors too.

It's like a "try and except" with the extra step of instanciating the function in a class.

```
def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))
```

Here it is the link 
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python